# Add error bars to grouped bar plot in MatLab

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, errorbar

I have a simple, grouped bar plot. I'm trying to plot the error bars, too, but I can't seem to figure it out.

I'm not too great with for loops, but I don't know if that's the only solution to this, or if I can just add another line of code to plot the error bars.

Here's my code and graph:

```
% Plot raw data
y = [316.45 292.14 319.96; 305.59 287.99 295.21]  % first 3 #s are pre-test, second 3 #s are post-test
err = [13.12 5.67 12.36; 12.43 6.83 11.67]

box on

bar(y)
set(gca,'xticklabel',{'Pre-test'; 'Post-test'}) 
ylim([200 360])
ylabel('RT (ms)')
xlabel('Session')
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to plot a grouped bar chart with errors bar as shown in the figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14256383/8239061)   (MATLAB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using the standard `errorbar` and `bar` functions. `bar` plots each group at the same `x` position, and uses the `Xoffset` property to shift the bars in a group. You can use the `x` position and `Xoffset` to plot the errorbars.

```
% Data
y = [316.45 292.14 319.96; 305.59 287.99 295.21]  % first 3 #s are pre-test, second 3 #s are post-test
err = [13.12 5.67 12.36; 12.43 6.83 11.67]

% Plot
figure(1); clf; 
hb = bar(y); % get the bar handles
hold on;
for k = 1:size(y,2)
    % get x positions per group
    xpos = hb(k).XData + hb(k).XOffset;
    % draw errorbar
    errorbar(xpos, y(:,k), err(:,k), 'LineStyle', 'none', ... 
        'Color', 'k', 'LineWidth', 1);
end

% Set Axis properties
set(gca,'xticklabel',{'Pre-test'; 'Post-test'});
ylim([200 360])
ylabel('RT (ms)')
xlabel('Session')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a simple enough for loop I can understand, I appreciate it

Comment: In R2019b and later, use [XEndpoints](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.bar-properties.html#mw_3d0c5b61-b082-4c79-b9c6-a21152ae26ff)